# XNA window border changing theme on Fullscreen to Windowed transition

Tags: c#, xna

When I'm going from fullscreen to windowed mode in XNA the window does not use the default windows theme but the old "non-aero" style. I'm using Windows 8, don't know the new terms for the different themes.

I tried this solution: [XNA losing title bar theme on fullscreen->windowed transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885363/xna-losing-title-bar-theme-on-fullscreen-windowed-transition), but it doesn't seem to work, at least not on Windows 8.

How do I make sure the default theme is always used? Doesn't have to be a XNA specific solution.

Comment: Just linking to [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885363/xna-losing-title-bar-theme-on-fullscreen-windowed-transition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

> System.Windows.Forms.Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled;

Comment: Works like a charm! Does this apply to Windows 7 as well?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, and this is my favorite code line on Pandora!