# XNA - Losing application-icon when returning from full screen

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

I've implemented the following (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541433/xna-window-border-changing-theme-on-fullscreen-to-windowed-transition?lq=1)) to return to the Aero-look of the window. Though it doesn't make sense that the Windows Forms assembly is needed for solving this. (Since it *does* have the Aero-look to begin with.)

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled;
```

(Implementing `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();` didn't work. Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885363/xna-losing-title-bar-theme-on-fullscreen-windowed-transition)  .)
But though I get the Aero-look - I lose the Application-icon.

**Before fullscreen:**

[image]

**After fullscreen:**

[image]

How do I get the icon back?

(I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. And using `graphics.ToggleFullScreen();` in the `Draw` method.)

Comment: Do you run/debug instance from VS or do you start it as stand-alone by running the exe-file? You probably never have an icon when debugging from VS

Comment: @DanielMesSer From VS. And yes, before posting I checked and _do_ have an icon before going fullscreen.

Comment: @DanielMesSer I also tried, now, as a standalone. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form MyGameForm = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Forms.Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
MyGameForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
```